# PHP waiting for response to change status

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle, skyscanner

I'm trying to implement SkyScanner API...

I need to call:

```
"http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk1/v1.0/
    {SessionKey}?apiKey={apiKey}
    &pageIndex=0
    &pageSize=10"
```

so I write:

```
$res1 = $client1->get('http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk2/v1.0/'.$session_id.'?apikey=APIKEY&pageIndex=0&pageSize=10"');

 $res1 = json_decode($res1->getBody()->getContents(), true);
$res1 = collect($res1);
```

and I need to wait for a response to change Status from `UpdatePending` to `UpdateCompleted`

API docs:

> Keep requesting page 0 until you get UpdatesComplete with pageIndex=0
>   at half a second to one second interval. Once you get UpdatesComplete
>   you may request any page and page size.
>
> While the status is UPDATESPENDING, you should request only page 0
>   because the contents of each page are liable to change until updates
>   are complete.

How to wait for response to change status...

I try:

```
while ($res1['Status'] == 'UpdatesPending') {
    echo 'waiting';
}

dd($res1);
```

but there is no end ...

How to wait for a response to change status?

Comment: You need a do/while loop. Request the status (the first 3 lines of your code) inside the loop, then break out of it when the status changes. Make sure you add a sleep to it, or you'll be spamming the heck out of their server until it changes.

Comment: @aynber please write as answer

Answer (score 0):

you can echo `'waiting'` before youre code
then it is be compleate echo `completed` in the other line

```
echo 'waiting...';
$res1 = $client1->get('http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk2/v1.0/'.$session_id.'?apikey=APIKEY&pageIndex=0&pageSize=10"');

$res1 = json_decode($res1->getBody()->getContents(), true);
$res1 = collect($res1);
echo 'completed';
```

Comment: no, thats not what I want! I need to call API and wait for res1 to changes status - $res1->STatus ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a do/while loop to check the status and break out of it when the status changes:

```
do{

    $res1 = $client1->get('http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk2/v1.0/'.$session_id.'?apikey=APIKEY&pageIndex=0&pageSize=10"');

    $res1 = json_decode($res1->getBody()->getContents(), true);
    $res1 = collect($res1);
    if($res1['Status'] == 'UpdatesPending') echo "waiting...<br />\n";
    sleep(5); // Make it sleep 5 seconds so as to not spam the server
while($res1['Status'] == 'UpdatesPending');

echo "Done!";
```

Note that you won't get any actual feedback until the whole process has finished.

Comment: Api simple pull data. Is there any other way then check status each 5seconds

Comment: Please check https://skyscanner.github.io/slate/#flights-browse-prices

Comment: The status won’t change in the response until you check it again.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `guzzle` as PHP HTTP Client, then you just need to define retry decider and retry timer

```
public function retryDecider() 
{
  return function ($retries, Request $request, Response $response = null, RequestException $exception = null) 
  {
    // maximum retries is three times
    if ($retries >= 3) {
      return false; 
    }

    if ($response) {
      $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();
      $res1 = json_decode($content, true);
      $res1 = collect($res1);

      // maybe you need to change this one to 'substr' or regex or something else
      if ($res1['Status'] == 'UpdatesComplete') {
        return false;
      }

    }

    return true; // we will request again
  };
}

public function retryDelay()
{
    return function ($numberOfRetries) {
        return 1000; // 1 second
    };
}
```

and use that decider and delay function

```
$handlerStack = HandlerStack::create(new CurlHandler());
$handlerStack->push(Middleware::retry($this->retryDecider(), $this->retryDelay()));
$client = new Client(array('handler' => $handlerStack));
```

and get your response

```
$url = 'http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/uk2/v1.0/'.$session_id.'?apikey=APIKEY&pageIndex=0&pageSize=10"';
$response = $client->request('GET', $url)->getBody()->getContents();
```

You can decode the last `$response` to decide want you want to do.

With this kind of approach, you can decide which response is valid and retry the request as many as you like.